# How to cast the column to datetime

Tags: r

I am importing datetime from tick files and the datetime format as the milliseconds in it. How do i convert it to r DateTime format? i get a error "Error in C_valid_tz(tzone) : object 'DateTime' not found"

```
library(tidyverse)

library(lubridate)

str<- "DateTime,BidOpen,BidHigh,BidLow,BidClose,AskOpen,AskHigh,AskLow,AskClose
01/03/2017 00:00:00.000,0.96739,0.96739,0.967,0.96715,0.96968,0.96968,0.96714,0.96722
01/03/2017 00:01:00.000,0.96715,0.96725,0.96715,0.9672,0.96722,0.96737,0.9672,0.96737
01/03/2017 00:02:00.000,0.9672,0.9672,0.96691,0.96705,0.96737,0.96737,0.96704,0.9672"

csv=read.csv(text=str,header=TRUE)
head(csv)


class(csv)

tib=as_tibble(csv)
tib %>%
  as_datetime(DateTime)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the function inside `mutate`. Assuming the format of `DateTime` is DD/MM/YYYY you can use `dmy_hms` from `lubridate` (If the format is MM/DD/YYYY use `mdy_hms`).

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

tib <- tib %>% mutate(DateTime = dmy_hms(DateTime))

# A tibble: 3 x 9
#   DateTime            BidOpen BidHigh BidLow BidClose AskOpen AskHigh AskLow AskClose
#  <dttm>                <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>
#1 2017-03-01 00:00:00   0.967   0.967  0.967    0.967   0.970   0.970  0.967    0.967
#2 2017-03-01 00:01:00   0.967   0.967  0.967    0.967   0.967   0.967  0.967    0.967
#3 2017-03-01 00:02:00   0.967   0.967  0.967    0.967   0.967   0.967  0.967    0.967
```